# Oscillation of a function on a set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Oscillation of function $f$ on $C$ is defined as follows:
$$ \omega_f(C)=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: x, y \in C\}.$$

Is true that if for any $\varepsilon >0$, $\omega_f(C) <\varepsilon$ then the restriction function $f$ to $C$ is continuous?

My attempt:
Given any $\varepsilon>0$, then
$$\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: x, y \in B_{\varepsilon}(u) \cap C\}<\varepsilon,$$
for all $u \in C$.

Therefore,
$$\omega_f(u,C)= \inf_{\varepsilon>0}\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: x, y \in B_{\varepsilon}(u) \cap C\}=0.$$
Otherwise, $\omega_f(u,C)=a$ and $a >0$. So, for any $\varepsilon >0$,
$$\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: x, y \in B_{\varepsilon}(u) \cap C\}\geq a.$$
Now, take $h= \frac{a}{2}$. Then, we have
$$\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: x, y \in B_{\varepsilon}(u) \cap C\}\leq h= \frac{a}{2}.$$
This contradiction shows that $\omega_f(u,C)=0$.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: If I were grading this argument, my questions would be: 1. What are you attempting to prove? 2. What does the displayed line immediately after "My attempt..." have to do with the definition of oscillation? (Given your definitions, if $\omega_{f}(C) < \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, you can deduce much more than "$f$ is continuous on $C$" with very little work.)